Any details about the Telophoroi?
While playing Final Fantasy 14, in the expansions of Shadowbringers, the Ascian Fandaniel mentioned that he's part of a faction called Telophoroi.
Assuming it's some detail I forgot about, I looked for it now online, just to find out there's no official or even semi-official details about it.
The only "source" I could find is a Reddit discussion, where someone asked this very same question just to get answers like "It's only Fandaniel and Zenos" etc. There is also no mention of this in the wiki page for Fandaniel.
Hopefully someone can shed some more light over this faction and its history.

That really is the extent of it. We're not given any indication that there are other Ascians working with them, nor that the faction existed before Fandaniel approached Zenos and agreed upon their shared goals, nor that Fandaniel had been doing anything at all to work towards these goals either alone or with others prior to allying with Zenos.
It is simply the name Fandaniel has given to the Fandaniel/Zenos alliance and the mind-controlled workers and soldiers that they have at their disposal.
